# ActiveRecord Migrations multiple databases

Tags: activerecord, rails-migrations

I need to move some of my tables in the current schema to a different database, as I need to turn off binary logging for these tables and Mysql doesnt allow turning off binary logging for a specific tables.

So i was wondering if i could run migrations on two different schemas in the same project.

Answer (score 0):

You can define separate databases in database.yml and manage different migrations directories for each:

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=customenvironment


db
  |- migrate (default migrate directory)
  |- schema.rb
  |- seed.rb

another_db (customenvironment)
  |- migrate (migrations for the second db)
  |- schema.rb (schema that will be auto generated for this db)
  |- seed.rb (seed file for the new db)
```